# Visual Studio Code Debug Console does not show the relevant error-causing widget

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#07556 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was:
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

This is the output of the Debug Console.
Whenever I encounter an error it does not show which widget was causing it (It happened on multiple occasions). I got the actual errors solved by guessing which widget caused it, but since I want to grow my project, that will no longer be feasible.

I have tried flutter doctor, and flutter doctor -v in the terminal and it did not show any issues. I have updated VS Code, and the Dart and Flutter Plugins. I cant seem to find this problem online.